# Accessing Editable Annotations

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a simple Dash application with a plot that updates when the 'Update' button is clicked. I've included an editable annotation on this graph. I want to be able to access whatever the user typed into the annotation so when the graph is updated, the annotation stays the same. I'm mostly wondering if there's a way to access how they edited it.

I've been trying to save the current annotation into a storage component which is accessed when the graph is created. I tried making a 'Save' button that changes the storage data to the current annotation text My only guess is that when the annotation is edited, the new text isn't stored in the same place that the default text was. That, or something is just going over my head, and I don't realize it.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, State, Output
import random

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

app.layout = html.Div(
    id = 'top_level',
    children=[
        html.Div(
            id='plot_div',
            children=[],
        ),

        html.Button(
            id = 'update',
            children="Update",
        ),

        dcc.Store(
            id='annotation_storage',
            data='Editable Annotation',
        )
    ]
)
@app.callback(
    Output('plot_div', 'children'),
    [Input('update', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('annotation_storage', 'data')]
)
def plot_update(clicked, annotation):
    if clicked:
        x = random.sample(range(1,101), 20)
        y = random.sample(range(1,101), 20)
        figure = {'data': [{'x': x, 'y': y, 
                            'type': 'scatter', 'mode': 'markers'}],
                  'layout': {
                      'xaxis': {
                          'fixedrange': True,
                          'zeroline': False,
                      },
                      'yaxis': {
                          'fixedrange': True,
                          'zeroline': False,
                      },
                      'annotations': [{
                            'x': -0.05,
                            'y': 0.5,
                            'showarrow':False,
                            'text':annotation,
                            'xref':'paper',
                            'yref':'paper',
                            }],
                        }
                  }
        return [dcc.Graph(
            id = 'plot_output',
            figure = figure,
            config = {
                'editable': True,
                'edits': {
                    'axisTitleText': False,
                    'titleText': False,
                },
                'displayModeBar': False,
            },
        ),
        html.Button(
            id = 'save_annotation',
            children='Save',
        ),
        ]

@app.callback(
    Output('annotation_storage', 'data'),
    [Input('save_annotation', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('plot_output', 'figure')]
)
def save_annotation(clicked, figure):
    if clicked:
        annotation = figure['layout']['annotations'][0]['text']
        return annotation
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=1000)
```

Currently the annotation is just reverting to the default text "Editable Annotation" when the graph is updated, even when the user edits it. I want the annotation to remain the same even when the graph is updated. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [Dash user guide](https://dash.plot.ly/interactive-graphing):

> The `dcc.Graph` component has four attributes that can change through
>   user-interaction: `hoverData`, `clickData`, `selectedData`, `relayoutData`.

This implies that the `figure` attribute you use is not updated when the user interacts with the graph.

To fix your problem, update your callback function to use `relayoutData` instead of `figure`:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('annotation_storage', 'data'),
    [Input('save_annotation', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('plot_output', 'relayoutData')]
)
def save_annotation(clicked, relayout_data):
    if clicked:
        annotation = relayout_data['annotations[0].text']
        return annotation
```

You can run your app in debug mode, and add a break-point inside of the callback function to explore the values given by the four aforementioned attributes. That's what I did to find the key for the annotation text inside of `relayout_data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y")
## TODO - load init annotations to fig.layout.annotations


dash_app1.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Hi there, I am dashboard1'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig,
        config={
            'editable': True,
            'edits': {
                'axisTitleText': False,
                'titleText': False,
            },
        }
    )
    ])

@dash_app1.callback(
    Output('example-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('example-graph', 'clickData'),
     Input('example-graph', 'relayoutData')],
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def annotation(clickData, relayoutData):
    if clickData:
        # get click xy
        point = clickData["points"][0]
        # if not exist, add
        if f"'x': {point['x']}, 'y': {point['y']}" not in str(fig.layout.annotations):
            fig.add_annotation(x=point["x"], y=point["y"], text="Click Here To Edit")
            print("Add: ", fig.layout.annotations)
        else:
            # if exist, edit
            if relayoutData:
                fig.plotly_relayout(relayoutData)
                print("Edit: ", fig.layout.annotations)

    ## TODO - save fig.layout.annotation
    return fig
```

Shovalt's answer is great, and thanks for your inspiration. I used `clickData` event to add annotation and use `relayoutData` event to record editing and dragging position. This updating can simply be done by `fig.plotly_relayout` and this is not included in the documentation. I took advantage from JS plotly. To be honest, Plotly Dash documentation is not enough developer-friendly, especially for beginners like me. Make sure you enabled code completion in your IDE, sometimes it's more helpful than the documentation...

Also, the `dcc.Store` is a little bit repeating here, because you can find all the annotations in `fig.layout.annotations`. Be careful with `dcc.Store`, it has a memory limitation as the doc mentioned: `It's generally safe to store up to 2MB in most environments, and 5~10MB in most desktop-only applications.`

#### Update:

I found this relayoutData listener may cause zooming unavailable, but I think it work with this now

```
@dash_app1.callback(
    Output('example-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('example-graph', 'clickData'),
     Input('example-graph', 'relayoutData')],
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def annotation(clickData, relayoutData):
    print("Click")
    print(clickData)
    print("Relayout")
    print(relayoutData)
    if clickData:
        ## get click xy
        point = clickData["points"][0]
        ## if not exist, add
        if f"'x': {point['x']}, 'y': {point['y']}" not in str(fig.layout.annotations):
            fig.add_annotation(x=point["x"], y=point["y"], text="Click Here To Edit")
            print("Add: ", fig.layout.annotations)
            ## TODO - save fig.layout.annotations to SQLite
            return fig
    if relayoutData:
        ## initial loading or refreshing action
        if str(relayoutData) == "{'autosize': True}":
            return fig
        ## zooming action
        ## enable zooming after resetting zooming
        if 'xaxis.range' in str(relayoutData) and 'yaxis.range' in str(relayoutData):
            fig.layout.xaxis.autorange = False
            fig.layout.yaxis.autorange = False
        ## edit annotation position or text | also enable zooming after resetting
        fig.plotly_relayout(relayoutData)
        print("Edit: ", fig.layout.annotations) 
        ## TODO - If edit, then update fig.layout.annotations to SQLite
    return fig
```